# Is there a way to infer the return type of a function parameter of a generic function type definition?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type definition for a "Middleman" function like this:

```
type Middleman = (
    callback: () => any
) => any
```

This function does "some task", then calls "callback" and returns its value. Right now both Middleman and the callback are typed to return any, but I would like to strongly type this.

I have tried introducing a type parameter like so:

```
type Middleman<T> = (
    callback: () => T
) => T
```

But this causes issue when trying to create an implementation of this function:

```
const middlemanImpl: Middleman<T> = cb => cb(); // Error, no way to get T here
```

As Middleman expects a "T" and can't seem to infer it from each call site.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish here? That is: a type definition for a generic function that returns the type of the return value of a function passed as an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want `Middleman` to really be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that refers to a specific function:

```
type BadMiddleman<T> = (callback: () => T) => T;
```

In this version, you cannot mention the type `BadMiddleman` without specifying the type parameter `T`.  And once you do that, any call to the function has to use that specified type `T`:

```
const numMiddleman: BadMiddleman<number> = cb => cb();
numMiddleman(() => 12); // okay
numMiddleman(() => "abc"); // error
```

---

Instead, you want `Middleman` to be a specific type that refers to a generic function.  The difference is in the scope of the generic type parameter:

```
type Middleman = <T>(callback: () => T) => T;
const middlemanImpl: Middleman = cb => cb(); // okay
```

Now it is the *call* to a function of type `Middleman` which decides what type `T` is:

```
const num = middlemanImpl(() => 12); // okay
num.toFixed();

const str = middlemanImpl(() => "abc"); // okay
str.toUpperCase();
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgEwLIEsEIDYQLZwHYA8AKgHxQC8UAFAMZwYYBGcNA1gFzUCUFZRP5PgG4AUCJoB7PAGdgUPAFdsqdFlx5O8ZGkw58BRdkYQATmUo1GvKJapdRhlbvVU71gIwAme1AD0vqAlWOBARRx01fFcBMgAiOEYaWJ9-KFMTCRMxEVBIKCdIvAooYhJaeiYWDm5rflrRSRk5bAi9PABJbDAMTgK24strWxSAoJCxRtl5JWKW1TbO7uiPbwclADpgCQAxFAAPCAQ7UXEpKdkTWdb1RYxlwSh4xOTRC82JAFUwSBMAYThpBBjkA)